# How to use iPhone WiFi on your Windows 7 PC wirelessly?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, iphone

I have a laptop running Windows 7 that I use a lot, but sadly one day I broke a part of it and after repairing it, I found out that my computer had very low WiFi signals, I mean that I have to get very close to my router which has a fixed location in order to connect via wifi. So I mostly use my PC in one place only and I can't move to other rooms without losing connection.

Recently I bought a new iPhone and I thought that maybe I could link my PC to the phone wirelessly (Via bluetooth) or another technology and use the WiFi connection from it while I'm away from the router (in other rooms) since my iPhone has very good signals even when it's away.

I'm sure that the problem is not with the router, I recently bought the latest D-Link model and the problem still occurs.

To simplify my question here's how it should work:

> PC/Laptop ---- > Iphone ---> Home WiFi Router

*Note : I'm not looking on how to create a hotspot on iOS, this won't help me*.

Thank's for your time.

Comment: Does your laptop support BlueTooth and is that receiver also malfunctioning?

Answer (score 0):

You will not find an app for that, as Apple does not allow apps to make use of "undocumented API's".

Is your iDevice jailbroken? If positive, you can achieve that funcionality by installing [MyWi 9](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.mywi4/) or [PDANet](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.jft.pn/) tweaks from Cydia store.